# Nested Eager loading relationships in Laravel

Tags: laravel, eloquent, laravel-5, laravel-blade

I am creating a forum software using Laravel and I'm trying to access the most recent posts made within a specific topic using `latestPost` as defined in my model below

```
    public function latestPost() {
        return $this->hasOne('App\Post')->with('thread')->with('author')->latest();
    }
```

Here is how the nested relationships are defined in `App\Post.php`

```
public function author()
{
    return $this->belongsTo('App\User', 'author_id');
}

public function thread()
{
    return $this->belongsTo('App\Thread', 'thread_id');
}

public function topic() {
    return $this->belongsTo('App\Topic');
}
```

I have been able to access posts of threads, authors etc no problem, and when I have `{{ $topic->latestPost }}` in my views, it will list the object including relationships successfully. But as soon as I try to display a specific part such as `{{ $topic->latestPost->author->username }}` I am getting the following error: `Trying to get property of non-object`

In this specific view, topics is yet another relationship pulled from Categories like so in the Controller and getting `$topics` using a `@foreach` on `$categories->topics`:

```
public function index() {
  $categories = Category::orderBy('order', 'asc')->get();

  return view('welcome', compact('categories'));
}
```

Here is a dump of `$categories`: http://dumptext.com/H8Nq16ea

Comment: can you print your this object ` $categories = Category::orderBy('order', 'asc')->get();` and add up dump array results in your question ?

Comment: Added at the bottom! It's quite long so I dumped it on dumptext.

Comment: ca you add `->toArray()` wtih your this line `$categories = Category::orderBy('order', 'asc')->get();` like this `$categories = Category::orderBy('order', 'asc')->get()->toArray();` and then provide the dump results.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you want to use nested eager loading.

Change: `return $this->hasOne('App\Post')->with('thread')->with('author')->latest();`

To this: `return $this->hasOne('App\Post')->with('thread.author')->latest();`

Also i never heard about latest() and the end of your return statement. Maybe you can try it with orderBy as shown below.

```
`return $this->hasOne('App\Post')->with('thread.author')->orderBy('id')->first;`
```

I guess you can use the orderBy('id')->reverse() function if the result is not in the order you want.  Let me know if it helped you out.

Comment: If i loaded the relationships that way, I'd be getting the thread's author and not the post's author.

Answer (score 0):

You should make sure you have author for latest post you want to display. Otherwise if you expect not to have one for each record, you should try:

```
{{ $topic->latestPost->author ? $topic->latestPost->author->username : 'No author' }}
```

In addition instead of:

```
return $this->hasOne('App\Post')->with('thread')->with('author')->latest();
```

you can use

```
return $this->hasOne('App\Post')->with('thread','author')->latest();
```

Comment: Thanks for the tip with condensing the with! Unfortunately, I'm still getting an error. If I echo just $topic->latestPost, all the author information is in the object, I just can't seem to access it...